# create buddy class for auto generated desgner.cs with Database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations, buddy-class

I want to create a buddy class, for the autogenerated Designer.cs in Datafirst Entity Framework, to implement validations with dataannotations.

The solutions I found on google contains examples with simple properties like

```
public int EmpID
{get;set;}
```

whereas the properties generated in designer.cs contains some logic in it. for ex-

```
/// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Byte RoleID
    {
        get
        {
            return _RoleID;
        }
        set
        {
            OnRoleIDChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("RoleID");
            _RoleID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("RoleID");
            OnRoleIDChanged();
        }
    }
```

Please guide on how to create a buddy class for properties like the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial classes to create a buddy class for properties like the one mentioned above. Take a look at this article: [Entity Framework using Partial classes to add business logic and validation to generated entities](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/31/entity-framework-using-partial-classes-to-add-business-logic-and-validation-to-generated-entities/)

If you need to create numerous buddy classes and there is a consistent pattern, then consider using code generation: [Customize the code generated by the Entity Designer with T4 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx)

Comment: Tarzan- Sorry but I cant access the 1st link due to web sense blocking it. and for 2nd link, I couldn't get it. Do you mean to say that I should put the dataannotations in the cs file generated by choosing the "ADO.NET EntityObject Generator" Template or Self Tracking Template. Please guide as I am novice to EF also.

Comment: @VirendraTamrakar instead of the 1st link, here is another article that is on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850404/using-partial-classes-in-entity-framework-with-custom-properties

Comment: Tarzan- The link doesnt seem to be ralted with validations or data annotations

Comment: It shows how to create buddy classes for Entity Framework objects by using partial classes. You can add the validation and data annotation pieces to the partial classes.